# Adding signature to google inbox programmatically

Tags: gmail-api, google-inbox

With using the google gmail api, we were able to update signatures of users within our google account.

But we noticed that when people use google inbox, the signature does not append. So far I have not seen any api that points to doing this.

Can it be done?

Or any link to some api that I must have missed would be helpful.

Comment: I don't see any related documentations regarding your issue. You may file a [report or feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191602&template=824107) for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Gmail and Inbox do not share the same signature settings. Since there is no API for Inbox it isn't possible to programmatically set the signature in Inbox.